Compose Focus Order Not making any sense
I have a pretty basic layout.
val focusRequesters = List(3) { FocusRequester() }

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.
        focusProperties {
            next = focusRequesters[0]
        }
) {
    Box {
        ...
        Box(
             modifier = 
                 Modifier               
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .focusRequester(focusRequesters[0])
            ) {
            // 0..n boxes of size > 0
        }
        ...
    }
}

The gist is basically a Box overlay of content that doesn't have a good way of focusing in compose. This Box should be used to trigger and interact all touching that should be interacted with the below component. Which I'm aware will cause other logical issues, but it's the current path that actually works so far.
However, what is happening doesn't make sense. When I load the page with TalkBack the Box with the requester is focused immediately (not expected). The next component to gain focus after that is the top of the page. When you naturally flow from the top of the page to the point where the Box SHOULD gain focus it is not gained and instead an internal box that does make sense as being the first focusable when inside the box gains focus. However, the wrapping Box gains focus as the LAST element. Which makes no sense at all.
The order to my understanding SHOULD be:

Box -> InternalBox1 -> InternalBox2 -> etc.. -> FocusRequester.Default

Does anyone have any idea what concept I'm missing?
